# understanding prototype or Map.prototype in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

understanding Map.prototype  javascript

Hi all... 
I have gone through many example and tutorials to understand what Map.prototype  actually represents..
 in some blogs i saw that it represents Map object but if i have created two Map objects in the same file which one it will refer to?
 and  can anyone please tell what the below condition mean?

```
var temp = Map.prototype ? new Map() : {} ;
```

are they checking if any objects of Map created if yes then create new object??

Comment: [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Comment: You should research and READ a little bit : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/prototype  AND https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: yes Andreas... i want to know how javascript  .prototype work

Answer (score 1):

That condition is very strange, for more than one reason.

1. It *looks* like it's trying to see if `Map` is supported by the JavaScript engine it's running on (`Map` was introduced in ES2015, not all engines have it yet), but the check is flawed and will actually throw an error if the implementation doesn't have `Map`. The check should be at least:

   ```
   var temp = typeof Map != "undefined" && Map.prototype ? new Map() : {} ;
   ```
2. The end result is that you have `temp` which might be a plain object, or might be a `Map` instance. But you don't use `Map` instances and plain objects the same way, so it's strange to do that.

Frankly, I wouldn't worry about that line (and I'd be wary of it and the code around it).

> I have gone through many example and tutorials to understand what Map.prototype actually represents.. I have gone through many example and tutorials to understand what Map.prototype actually represents.. in some blogs i saw that it represents Map object but if i have created two Map objects in the same file which one it will refer to?

The object that `Map.prototype` refers to is the object that will be used as the prototype of `Map` instances. That is:

```
let m1 = new Map();
let m2 = new Map();
```

Both of those instances will share the same underlying prototype object, which is the one that `Map.prototype` referred to.

That underlying prototype is what gives the instances various features, like the `get` and `set methods.

This aspect of your question is covered in more detail in [*How does JavaScript .prototype work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work).